# Word for package of developed pictures

Tags: single-word-requests

Ever gone to Walmart or Walgreens and developed a set of pictures? I'm looking for a word the package of pictures that is produced as a bundle, with the pictures and negatives.

Words like `set` or `bundle` come to mind but don't seem to fit exactly and `gallery` doesn't seem to either.

Comment: I don't know of a word for such a set, offhand. But it used to be that each such "set" corresponded to one **roll** of film.

Comment: *Set* works, actually - e.g. "two *sets* of prints".

Comment: I also thought *roll*. You used a word, ***package***, which I think fits nicely, so long as there is context for its contents.

Comment: *Set*, as Lawrence said. *Set of pictures* or *set of prints* or *set of negatives* or pretty-much anything you like…

How could making them *pictures* and *prints* change anything significant, please?

Comment: I've seen "prints" on its own, eg "You can pick up your prints after 2 hours".

Comment: @Drew, indeed, they were developed per _roll_, but the OP seems to confound _development_ and _print_, which is probably not that strange. With the rise of digital fotography, pictures obviously don't get developed anymore, just printed, and even in the old days, you didn't necesssarily print the whole roll of film.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a "booklet," "folder," or "envelope" of photos?

Comment: This should really be a comment with the current formatting. Could you add a definition for each word with why it's appropriate?